# My command runs in bash, but not from /etc/init, what have I done wrong?

Tags: upstart, init

I'm having some trouble with this init script.

When I run the command I'm passing to start-stop-daemon from the command line it works perfectly, even if I run it sudoed as the userid in the script, but for some reason the command:

```
sudo service start deluged
```

prints this:

```
deluged start/stopping
```

but I can't see any deluged processes using `top`, `htop` or `ps aux`, and I can't connect to it on the port it's supposed to be listening to (or any other port).

I'm out of ideas for what to try next. Running the init script fails before anything is written to the logfile, so I have no idea what's going wrong.

I'm 100% convinced the user and group exist and aren't typoed, but it's possible they're misconfigured in some way, since I made them manually and might have missed something. I'm also pretty sure that user has permission to access all the relevant files for the program.

Here's the script, I have no idea what I've done wrong (and I took most of this from the deluged documentation anyway!)

```
#deluged - Deluge daemon                                                                                                                         
#                                                                                                                                                 

# The daemon component of Deluge BitTorrent client. Deluge UI clients                                                                             
# connect to this daemon via DelugeRPC protocol.                                                                                                  



description "Deluge daemon"                                                                                                                       
author "Deluge Team"                                                                                                                              

start on filesystem and static-network-up                                                                                                         
stop on runlevel [016]                                                                                                                            

respawn                                                                                                                                           
respawn limit 5 30                                                                                                                                

env uid=debian-deluged                                                                                                                            
env gid=debian-deluged                                                                                                                            
env umask=007                                                                                                                                     

exec start-stop-daemon -S -c $uid:$gid -k $umask -x /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluged -L info -l /var/log/deluged/server.log -c /var/opt/deluged/config -p 8112 -- -d
```

Comment: I'd strip out start-stop-daemon. You don't need it because that's what upstart is managing for you.

Comment: And the last line seems to be incorrectly broken into two lines.

Comment: that line isn't split in vim, it's just an artifact of the pasting. I guess I'll try it without the start-stop-daemon

Comment: how do I get init to hand off to another user before running the exec block? I'd rather not have my bittorrent daemon running as root...

Comment: `setu/gid`: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setgid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The deluge docs have something similar to yours but I think this is a hangover from very old versions of Upstart. I'd try simplifying it down to something like this first:

```
description "Deluge daemon"
author "Deluge Team"

start on filesystem and static-network-up
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

setuid debian-deluged
setgid debian-deluged
umask 007

exec /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluged -L info -l /var/log/deluged/server.log -c /var/opt/deluged/config -p 8112 -- -d
```

And then if that still doesn't work, check the permissions on `/var/log/deluged/` and `/var/log/deluged/server.log` (that the `debian-deluged` user can write there). If it's still not working then, the upstart log files might help you out. Yours will be `/var/log/upstart/deluged.log`. If that shows nothing, we could just try launching the command as the right user:

```
sudo -u debian-deluged -g debian-deluged /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/deluged -L info -l /var/log/deluged/server.log -c /var/opt/deluged/config -p 8112 -- -d
```

Comment: are you sure about that `-- -d` on the end? I had thought that was an option on start-stop-daemon, but I could be wrong?

Comment: I'm currently trying a variant on this which sets an expect directive as well, since the upstart docs said never to use a respawn directive without one. It now actually launches, but hangs when I try to use `sudo service deluged stop`. Which feels like there's still a problem with the file.

Comment: Am I sure about the `-- -d`? Not at all. The [deluge-suggested version](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/Upstart) has a much more simple command line (though they're still using stop-start-daemon for no good reason). It's using the default locations for config and logs which should be good enough.

Comment: If it's stopping the process (check top, etc) and it's just upstart that is hanging, Control+C and carry on with your day. I've had similar issues with some upstart scripts that fork out but it's still doing the correct job. If it's not managing to kill it off, that's a bigger problem.