# Deluged Upstart not starting

Tags: 14.04, upstart, services, init.d, deluge

Setting up a new ubuntu server installation (14.04.1), I have been completely unable to get deluge to start as a daemon at system startup. Originally tried following this set of instructions: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/Upstart

I have tried / read countless questions and answers on stackexchange, as well as various other guides and posts by people having similar issues.

I am baffled to the point where I created an account on here to post, and see if I could get another set of eyes on this. I set this up once before on 14.04 running on a different system, and had no troubles at all.

On boot: not running, verified by `ps -aux |grep delu`
Something I just noticed, when I enter `sudo service d` and attempt to use tab completion, "deluged" is not one of the available options, however if I type it in manually, `sudo service deluged start` returns `deluged start/running, process 1475`

Checking `ps -aux |grep delu` returns that is is running, however at 1482. The web-ui, which should have been started when the daemon was, is not however.

An immediate `sudo service deluged status` returns `deluged stop/waiting` rather than  `deluged start/running, process XXXX` which it should be. However, checking ps -aux right after that shows deluged running with the perimeters from the upstart script.

Any other information that would help I am happy to provide. I attempted the solution from [My command runs in bash, but not from /etc/init, what have I done wrong?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568867/my-command-runs-in-bash-but-not-from-etc-init-what-have-i-done-wrong/569125#569125) but all it did was change to `sudo service deluged start`the `deluged starting/stopping` message that they started with.

Unfortunately I am reusing the SSD I originally had it set up on in my new system, or I would look at how I had managed it there. I thought I might have used init.d rather than upstart, but I tried that as well, and it didn't work either.

```
$ cat deluged.conf    
description "Deluge daemon"

start on filesystem and static-network-up
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

setuid deluge
setgid deluge
umask 007

exec /usr/bin/deluged -d

$ cat deluge-web.conf
description "Deluge Web UI"

start on started deluged
stop on stopping deluged

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

setui deluge
setgid deluge
umask 027

exec /usr/bin/deluge-web
```

Comment: What if you manually run `sudo -u deluge /usr/bin/deluge-web`?

Comment: Ok, actually, cleaning up the deluged.conf file and adding back in the -d tag worked, and it is now properly running / restarting, etc. Deluge-web however, is not starting, and attempting to start the service returns 
`$ sudo service deluge-web start`
`start: Unknown job: deluge-web`

Comment: that maybe because you have a typo - `setui` instead of `setuid`. I assumed it was a copying error.

Comment: `[ERROR   ] 13:23:35 common:167 Unable to use default config directory, exiting... ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ken/.config/deluge')`

Comment: nope, I'm that big of an idiot. Must have snuck in when I was cleaning out env variables.

Comment: all appears to be working now, although for some reason, tab complete still does not appear to be recognizing deluged or deluge-web as services, when I type them manually the commands work as expected.

Comment: What happens if you use the `start` and `stop` commands instead of `service`?  Like `sudo start del<TAB>`?

Comment: That is working, and I just found a reference that it should not tab complete on `sudo service` for custom upstart jobs, so it is working.