# deluge daemon crashes: There is a deluge daemon running with this config directory!

Tags: upstart, deluge

I am having a similar problem as described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/533423/deluge-daemon-continues-to-crash. I am sure, however, there are no deluge processes in the background when I start the daemon service.

Here is my process (includes commands, logs, etc.): http://paste.ubuntu.com/12504292/

Here is my /etc/init/deluged.conf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12504300/

I must be doing something wrong, and alas, I'm getting frustrated. The documentation for Deluge Upstart seems out of date as it utilizes start-stop-daemon; however, I found an example conf file that appears to have an updated approach. For more information regarding this:
[My command runs in bash, but not from /etc/init, what have I done wrong?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/568867/my-command-runs-in-bash-but-not-from-etc-init-what-have-i-done-wrong)

*Note: I would paste the link to Deluge Upstart guide, but I am limited to a single external link in this post.*

Comment: I appear to have resolved this issue by commenting out the following lines from the /etc/init/deluged.conf file:
`respawn` and `respawn limit 5 30`

I wish deluge had better and more up to date documentation. So the above fixed my problem with the specific error mentioned above, but now I just have new application-specific errors that seem to be unrelated. I'll likely attempt to find an alternative.

Comment: So you stopped it respawning, I am not sure what that actually fixes. Lack of documentation on Deluge site is irrelevant, upstart is well documented. Not using `exec` is for compatibility but again not an issue relevant here. Also if deluged did crash it would leave behind a `pid` file as mentioned in the logs, did you verify it's existence? Anyway this is a bug report and a ticket should be either opened on Launchpad or Deluge site.

Comment: Please update with an acceptable answer